# how to set data expire time use pymongo

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

How to set data expire time use pymongo? I need set some important document's expire time, so I maybe use `db.collection.create_index([('expireAt', 1)], expireAfterSeconds=0)`. It means that I should set the value of `expireAt` to correspond to the time the document should expire. And I prefer using `mongodb` server's time to the local machine time (users can change their machine time).

How to use `pymongo` to do

```
newDate (new Date(now.getTime()+60000))
```

like mongoDB

Answer (score -1):

There are two mechanism using which you can ask Mongo to remove expired documents:

- Expire Documents after a Specified Number of Seconds
- Expire Documents at a Specific Clock Time

In your question, you seem to want to use "Expire Documents at a Specific Clock Time", but, you are trying to give current_time + x_seconds. If this is what you want, you should use "Expire Documents after a Specified Number of Seconds" mechanism.

**Example for Expiring Documents at a Specified Clock Time:**

```
db.log_events.createIndex( { "expireAt": 1 }, { expireAfterSeconds: 0 } )
db.log_events.insert( {
   "expireAt": new Date('July 22, 2013 14:00:00'),
   "logEvent": 2,
   "logMessage": "Success!"
} )
```

**Example for Expiring Documents after a Specified Number of Seconds**

```
db.log_events.createIndex( { "createdAt": 1 }, { expireAfterSeconds: 3600 } )
db.log_events.insert( {
   "createdAt": new Date(),
   "logEvent": 2,
   "logMessage": "Success!"
} )
```

More information can be found at:
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/expire-data/

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I want to use 'Expired Document At a Specific time', because the expire second is variable, maybe 60s, 1h, etc

Comment: Ok. I hope you got the information you needed. If the answer helped you, please consider upvoting and accepting the answer. Thanks!

Comment: The question was about using pymongo, but your answer is in JavaScript