# Mongodb cloud TTL index "expireAfterSeconds": 30 isn't working

Tags: database, mongodb, mongoose, indexing, ttl

this is my field and option.

[image]

I've added a new data in my cluster after creating this index. But my data is still in there.

How can I delete it automatically after 30 seconds? Index isn't working for me. I couldn't find another way to make it.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/76381650/6463558

Comment: Mann! U saved my day It solved for me

Comment: how can I make it as solved

Comment: Now, you have enough reputation to upvote the answer.